# Using variable from forms as DOM selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I thought I was past the point where I get tripped up on small stupid things but I can use some help. I'm trying to use a variable that is made from form input so select (either using JS or jQuery) an element by ID. The end goal is to remove certain elements in the HTML base on the selection.

Javascript/jQuery that I have and some things I've tried.

```
function showLocation() {
    var locationRef = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy"),
        locationChoice = locationRef.options[locationRef.selectedIndex].value,
        selectionChoice = document.getElementById("selectionChoice");

    (function() {
        $('#locationChoice').toggleClass("ClassHide");
        return false;
    })();
});
```

Instead of the $('#locationChoice') I've tried just $('locationChoice') and $(locationChoice).

When I console.log(locationChoice) I get the correct selection so I don't think its that.

I also tried without jQuery

```
locationChoice.classList.remove("classHide");
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return showLocation()" id="testLocation">
<h4>Please select a location</h4>
<select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="spotOne">Test Spot One</option>
    <option value="spotTwo">Test Spot Two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" form="testLocation" value="Submit">Select</button>
```

```
<div id="spotOne">
    <p>Remove Me One</p>
</div>
<div id="spotTwo">
    <p>Remove Me Two</p>
</div>
```

Any typo's or syntax errors may be from cleaning everything up and pasting it. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Not to answer your question, but generally, you want to stick to jQuery syntax or JavaScript/DOM. You have both. Additionally, your `showLocation` function doesn't actually return false as it is, because you've wrapped it in a IIFE (the `(function() {...})()`), which isn't necessary here.

Comment: FYI, `locationRef.options[locationRef.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `locationRef.value`.

Comment: And since you use jQuery, it can just be `$("#ddlViewBy").val();`

Comment: Thank you, concat and some clean-up on.value selectors worked well. Thank you for the help, I need to take more breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on top of @Quantastical answer.

There are actually 2 errors:

1. Given that locationChoice is a string we will need to do: 
   $('#' + locationChoice);
2. The immediate function within your function has a return, but your original function doesn't.

I don't quite understand the intent with the immediate function; however, simply add a `return` to make it work.

```
return (function() {
$("#" + locationChoice).toggleClass("ClassHide");
return false;
})();
```

or without the function:

```
$("#" + locationChoice).toggleClass("ClassHide");
return false;
```

See: [Working example](http://jsbin.com/bawoxiqoge/edit?html,js,output)

**Edit:** *Also make sure to check out @Barmar recommendation given as a comment to your post.*

Answer (score 3):

You just need to concatenate the '#' to your locationChoice variable.

```
$('#' + locationChoice)
```

Or change your values to be actual selectors:

```
<option value="#spotOne">...</option>
$(locationChoice);
```

Comment: I like having the values be actual selectors - it's a little more readable, and it's flexible in the event that you ever want to pass selectors other than ids

Answer (score 1):

If you change the way the toggleClass works to the following, it should fix the error:

```
$("#" + locationChoice).toggleClass("ClassHide");
```

This adds the "#" to whatever the locationChoice is that the user chooses.